# How do I run my Go application in the scratch container as the user "nobody?"

Tags: docker, go, linux-containers

I don't want to run anything in a docker container as root.
And I want minimalistic images.

I can run my compiled Go app in the scratch-image without a problem.
But when I don't want it to run as root (i assume its running as root)
and define USER nobody in the dockerfile I get

```
014/10/25 06:07:10 Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 
4822f34e54e20bb580f8cd1d38d7be3c828f28595c2bebad6d827a17b4c2fe21: 
finalize namespace setup user get supplementary groups Unable to find user nobody
```

here is my dockerfile

```
FROM scratch
ADD lichtpunkt_go_linux_amd64 /lichtpunkt_go_linux_amd64
ADD web /web
USER nobody
CMD ["./lichtpunkt_go_linux_amd64"]
EXPOSE 3001
```

EDIT ------------

turns out that scratch is empty, very empty.

RUN useradd would execute /bin/sh -c useradd
but there is no /bin/sh . 
RUN ["useradd"] would exec directly. 
but there is no useradd. 
i d have to add rootfs.tar and build stuff from zero.

i ll use debian as i don't wont to run anything as root within a container
because ...

> [Treat root within a container as if it is root outside of the
>   container](http://opensource.com/business/14/7/docker-security-selinux)

Comment: Use `COPY` instead of `ADD`. It is official recommendation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

turns out that scratch is empty, very empty.

RUN useradd would execute /bin/sh -c useradd but there is no /bin/sh . RUN ["useradd"] would exec directly. but there is no useradd. i d have to add rootfs.tar and build stuff from zero.

i ll use debian as i don't wont to run anything as root within a container because ...

> Treat root within a container as if it is root outside of the
>   container

http://opensource.com/business/14/7/docker-security-selinux

Comment: **Accept what answers the question, not what you ended up doing.**

Answer (score 12):

The solution is to use multi-stage build and copy `/etc/passwd`, as explained in this  nice [blog-post by Liz Rice](https://medium.com/@lizrice/non-privileged-containers-based-on-the-scratch-image-a80105d6d341).

Comment: Maybe people mistakenly voted this as "link-only" answer, but that's not the case. Idan, I made an edit to put the solution first so there's little room for doubt..

Answer (score 5):

Create a file with the following content and `COPY` it into the `scratch` container as `/etc/passwd`.

```
nobody:*:65534:65534:nobody:/_nonexistent:/bin/false
```

You can `COPY` `/bin/false` as well; or you don’t, in which case, attempts to log in as `nobody` will simply just fail.

```
su: failed to execute /bin/false: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2):

Before the `USER` command, add this line:
`ADD passwd.minimal /etc/passwd`

With the following line in the file passwd.minimal:
`nobody:x:65534:65534:Nobody:/:`

Comment: Use `COPY` instead of `ADD`. It is official recommendation.

Comment: The `passwd` record is **not secure.** Its `home-dir` field is the root directory, and `login-shell` field is empty, which defaults to `/usr/bin/sh` (if exists in the `scratch` container).

Answer (score -3):

You still have to add the user before you can use it with the USER command.

```
FROM scratch
ADD lichtpunkt_go_linux_amd64 /lichtpunkt_go_linux_amd64
ADD web /web
RUN useradd nobody
USER nobody
CMD ["./lichtpunkt_go_linux_amd64"]
EXPOSE 3001
```

Comment: turns out that scratch is empty. RUN useradd would execute /bin/sh -c. but there is no /bin/sh . RUN ["useradd"] would exec directly. but there is no useradd. i d have to add rootfs.tar and build stuff from zero. i ll use debian. thx